# JavaScript Date() GMT Setting

Tags: javascript, date, gmt

I have a userscript I'm writing.

The target page has a date shown, which I'm using JavaScript to turn into a new Date() object.

The page elements that tell the date get turned into a JavaScript date.

I then compare the pages now-JavaScript date object with the new Date() object (current local time) to work out the difference.

It all works well, except when there's a difference in the GMT settings of the two dates. The pages date might be GMT +1 whereas my local date is GMT +2.

Without changing the sites settings to display its dates in line with my GMT (but by still knowing what the sites GMT is set as), **how can I manipulate the GMT of either date?**

Comment: Have you looked at [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/)?

Comment: I'll take a gander now.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/timezone/ is another option

Comment: Vanilla JavaScript gives you three options; dates in the local timezone, dates in UTC/GMT (i.e. GMT+0), dates as milliseconds since the unix epoch. You can't predict the local timezone of someone accessing your site over the internet, so **store** all the dates in either of the latter two, and display them however you choose